# How to make password character into like ( • ) this in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi just wanna ask about how to change the password character into a bullet form  ( • ) like this. Here's the picture of my login form. I tried to set UseSystemPasswordChar to true but it only shows normal characters.

I put these codes given to me by Tom

```
public login()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.txtpassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
}
```

but it's still not working. Any other suggestions? Thank you!

[Login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niyYy.jpg)

Comment: what's this? web app or winform/wpf?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all UI frameworks (also web) have a password text field built-in - you just need to read the documentation of the framework you are using

Comment: I'm currently doing my system in C# winform

Comment: Is your form called Login? and I assume the `Textbox` is in the same form?

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. I made some changes in my codes and it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the properties of the `Textbox` to`UseSystemPasswordChar` to true

[image]

**Edit**

You could also call this when the form is first loaded:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.PasswordTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }
```

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: @Quinn, what do you mean are you getting any errors? when you change the properties and you type in the `textbox` is it just normal characters?

Comment: There are no errors. But when I try to run the program, it only shows the normal characters

Comment: @Quinn, Maybe edit your post with the code that you are using, like what your `textbox` is called stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. I made some changes in my codes and it works. :)

Comment: @Quinn, No worries :)

Comment: @Quinn, Don't forget to tick it as the Answer :) haha

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: When you accept an answer there is a tick (Just next to the voting buttons on the left hand side of the answer ) you press the tick and it lets other people know that your issue was resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the input type "password"
for it to do that :

```
<input type="password" />
```

Comment: How did you infer that OP is using HTML?

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. I made some changes in my codes and it works. :)